# glEnableClientState with modern OpenGL (glVertexAttribPointer etc)

Tags: opengl

I'd like to lay out some things I think I've learned, but am unsure about:

- VBOs are the way to go. They're created with `glGenBuffers` and `glBufferData`.
- For maximum flexibility, it's best to pass generic vertex attributes to shaders with `glVertexAttribPointer`, rather than `glVertex`, `glNormal`, etc..
- `glDrawElements` can be used with vertex buffers and an index buffer to efficiently render geometry with lots of shared vertices, such as a landscape mesh.

Assuming all of that is correct so far, here's my question. All of the tutorials I've read about modern OpenGL completely omit `glEnableClientState`. But the OpenGL man pages say that without `glEnableClientState`, `glDrawElements` will do nothing:

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml

The key passage is: "If `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` is not enabled, no geometric primitives are constructed."

This leads me to the following questions:

- None of the tutorials use `glEnableClientState` before calling `glDrawElements`. Does this mean the man page is wrong or outdated?
- `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` would seem to be the thing you enable if you're going to use `glVertexPointer`, and likewise you'd use `GL_NORMAL_ARRAY` with `glNormalPointer`, and so on. But if I'm not using those functions, and am instead using generic vertex attributes with `glVertexAttribPointer`, then why would it be necessary to enable `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> If GL_VERTEX_ARRAY is not enabled, no geometric primitives are constructed.

That's because the man page is *wrong*. The man page covers GL 2.1 (and it's still wrong for that), and for whatever reason, the people updating the man page refuse to update the older GL versions for bug fixes.

In GL 2.1, you must use either generic attribute index 0 or `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY`. In GL 3.1+, you don't need to use any specific attribute indices.

This is because, in GL versions before 3.1, all array rendering functions were defined in terms of calls to `glArrayElement`, which used immediate mode-based rendering. That means that you need something to *provoke* the vertex. Recall that, in immediate mode, calling `glVertex*()` not only sets the vertex position, it also causes the vertex to be sent with the other attributes. Calling `glVertexAttrib*(0, ...)` does the same thing. That's why older versions require you to use either attribute 0 or `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY`.

In GL 3.1+, once they took out immediate mode, they had to specify array rendering differently. And because of that, they didn't have to limit themselves to using attribute 0.

If you want API docs for core GL 3.3 works, I suggest you look at [the actual API docs for core GL 3.3](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/). Though to be honest, I'd just look at the spec if you want *accurate* information. Those docs have a lot of misinformation in them. And since they're not actually wiki-pages, that information *never* gets corrected.

Comment: "In GL 2.1, you must use either generic attribute index 0"--So in other words, if my GLSL program isn't using attribute 0, then "no geometric primitives are constructed," kind of like the man page says? BTW, I'm using 2.1 for Mac compatibility, and my program is working fine without glEnableClientState. But, I know for a fact that I am using generic attribute 0, which I suppose explains why my geometry is still being rendered.

Answer (score 2):

Your first 3 points are correct.  And to answer your last half of your question, do not use `glEnableClientState` for modern OpenGL.  Start coding!

Answer (score 1):

> VBOS are the way to go. They're created with glGenBuffers and
>   glBufferData.

VBOs are often used in high-performance applications. You might want to do something simpler first.  Vertex arrays can be a good way to go to get started quickly.  Because VBOs sit on top of vertex arrays anyway, you'll be using much of the same code when you switch to VBOs, and it might be good to run a test using vertex arrays or indexed vertex arrays first.

> For maximum flexibility, it's best to pass generic vertex attributes
>   to shaders with glVertexAttribPointer, rather than glVertex, glNormal,
>   etc..

That's a good approach.

> glDrawElements can be used with vertex buffers and an index buffer to
>   efficiently render geometry with lots of shared vertices, such as a
>   landscape mesh.

Perhaps. You have to be sure the vertices truly are shared, though. A vertex that is in the same location but has a different normal (e.g. for flat shading) isn't truly shared.

Comment: All useful information, but none of it actually answers the *question*.

Comment: Yes, Nicol is right. But thanks for the info! It's definitely helpful. I do have VBOs and glVertexAttribPointer working, so I'll stick with those. Your point about glDrawElements is well-taken--I understand what you mean about how the verts need to have exactly the same attributes for this approach to work.

Comment: OH, right, question.  The "could someone let me know if I'm wrong about this" part sort of sidetracked me.  Sorry.